# I am facing an ubuntu upgrade issue

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade

I am facing error in ubuntu when I upgrade to apt-get command and I am also facing a problem when I want to install a new program. this error appears:

```
najeeb@najeeb:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
[sudo] password for najeeb: 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-        security_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Does anyone have a solution for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/list*

$ sudo apt-get update
```